# laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables

**products**:id, code,details,created_at

**price_revision**:id,product_id,revised_price,user,remark,created_at,updated_at

i want to produce following json:

```
 {
"accessory_price":{[
"date":"2015-03-01",
"products":
{[ "product_id":1, "product_name":"test accessory 1", "revised_price":50.00, "user":"samyak", "remarks":"n/a" ], [ "product_id":2, "product_name":"test accessory 2", "revised_price":60.00, "user":"samyak", "remarks":"n/a" ], [ "product_id":3, "product_name":"test accessory 3", "revised_price":70.00, "user":"samyak", "remarks":"n/a" ]}
],
[
"updated_at":"2015-02-01",
"products":
{[ "product_id":1, "product_name":"test accessory 1", "revised_price":40.00,    "user":"sam", "remarks":"n/a" ], [ "product_id":2, "product_name":"test accessory 2", "revised_price":50.00, "user":"sam", "remarks":"n/a" ], [ "product_id":3, "product_name":"test accessory 3", "revised_price":60.00, "user":"sam", "remarks":"n/a" ]}
]
]}
```

I have made model like this:

**ProductModel**

```
public function productpricerevision(){
 return $this->hasMany('Modules\Quotes\Entities\ProductPriceRevision','product_id');

}
```

**Repository code**

```
 public function getProductPrice(){
$productprice=ProductModel::with('productpricerevision')->get();            
 $data=array('accessory_price'=>$productprice);
  return $data;

 }
```

But with this code I get

```
{
  "product_price": [
{
  "id": 1,

  "code": "G4007",     
  "detail": "Flyscreen Gasket -4007",
  "created_at": "2014-07-11 13:53:02",
   "productprice": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "product_id": 1,
      "revised_price": 78,
      "user": "sam",
      "remark": "test",
      "created_at": "2016-03-30 00:00:00",
      "updated_at": "2016-03-30 00:00:00"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "code": "CZBR-100S",
  "detail": "Single Bearing Roller BR-100-S",
   "created_date": "2014-07-11 13:57:15",
   "productprice": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "product_id": 2,
      "revised_price": null,
      "user": sam,
      "remark": null,
      "created_at": "2016-03-30 00:00:00",
      "updated_at": "2016-03-30 00:00:00"
    }
  ]
},
```

**Product Migration**

```
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('id');
        $table->string('code', 25);
        $table->text('detail', 65535)->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
                });
}


/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('products');
}

}
```

**price_revision**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_price_revision', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->double('revised_price')->nullable();
         $table->string('user')->nullable();
         $table->text('remark')->nullable();
          $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('CASCADE')->onUpdate('CASCADE');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('product_price_revision');
}
```

I have tried several other methods too but at the end i got lost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post up your migrations for creating the tables?

Comment: @Anderscc I have added my migration.thank you